# How to print type of polymorphic function (or value) in ghci with type defaulting rules applied?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, ghci, monomorphism-restriction

When I enter `:t` command in GHCi I see polymorphic type:

```
ghci> :t 42
42 :: Num t => t
ghci> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

But after I actually evaluate such functions I see result of type defaulting rules. Is there some command or ability to observe in ghci how type will be changed after type defaulting rules applied according to Haskell report and/or ghc implementation?

Comment: How do you see result of type defaulting rules? `:t 42 \`div\` 2` shows `Integral a => a`, and so do results of let-bindings etc.

Comment: @n.m. I was saying about actual result. Like `2^100 \`div\` 2` prints `633825300114114700748351602688` because default type for this case is `Integer`. Even if `ghci` says that type of this constant is polymorphic, in reality its specific and I want to see which monomorphic type is used.

Comment: @Shersh That's just GHCi though. The REPL picks a type (`Integer`, in this case) because it has to display something. In "real" code it'll be polymorphic until the context picks a type.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson In real code I can write `main = print (2 ^ 100)` and it will pick `Integer` type though emitting warning that I'm a bad person. This happens because type defaulting rules applied. I want to see which specific type `ghci` or `ghc` will pick. I don't care how it choses default type, I just want to see what type was chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GHC 8.4.1 it's possible to use `:type +d` (or `:t +d` for short) option to print the type of an expression, defaulting type variables if possible.

```
ghci> :t 42
42 :: Num p => p
ghci> :t +d 42
42 :: Integer
ghci> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
ghci> :t +d div
div :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by turning on the monomorphism restriction and then binding it to a new name:

```
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction 
Prelude> let n = 42
Prelude> :t n
n :: Integer
Prelude> let p = (^)
Prelude> :t p
p :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
Prelude> let e = (**)
Prelude> :t e
e :: Double -> Double -> Double
Prelude> let d = div
Prelude> :t d
d :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

If you don't fancy the need to always define a new variable, you can get around this by using

```
Prelude> :def monotype (\e -> return $ ":set -XMonomorphismRestriction\nlet defaulted = "++e++"\n:t defaulted")
```

(you may want to put that in your `.ghci` file to always have the command available) and then

```
Prelude> :monotype (^)
defaulted :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Of course, the hidden global side-effect of enabling the monomorphism restriction is extremely ugly, but oh well...

Comment: It does work for `div` for me (8.0.2). Perhaps ask for `:t d` :)

Comment: Yeah, also works in 8.3 and 7.10, when actually writing `:t d` instead of `:t div`. My fingers typed away too fast there...

Comment: That's really helpful! Not perfect (because I can't write `:t div`) but already good enough.

Comment: @Shersh I added a GHCi macro for the “perfect” solution to my answer.

Comment: If you want to default to `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, then you can add `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` at the end of the definition of `:monotype`. Also I would use an uncommon identifier like `__defaulted__` to avoid the potential for name clashes, or `it` so that GHCi will automatically overwrite the binding anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Not a perfect solution, but it could be a first step.

```
> import Data.Typeable
> let withType x = (x, typeOf x)
> withType []
([],[()])
> withType 56
(56,Integer)
```

Note that, since the type `a` gets changed into `(a,TypeRep)`, GHCi will not use all its defaulting magic. Still, some of it can be shown.

GHCi's `:set +t` option is also interesting, but prints the polymorphic type before the GHCi defaulting, it seems.

Comment: That's an interesting solution!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible for ghci to give you similar defaulting behaviour as GHC, which is exactly why the monomorphism restriction is (now) turned off by default in ghci.

As shown in @Shersh's answer, you can now ask GHCi what it would default a given expression to.

```
Prelude> :t 2^100 `div` 2
2^100 `div` 2 :: Integral a => a

Prelude> :t +d 2^100 `div` 2
2^100 `div` 2 :: Integer

Prelude> 2^100 `div` 2
633825300114114700748351602688
```

But this isn't necessarily reflective of what GHC would do with the same expression, since GHC compiles the expression in the context of the full module. GHC can take into account all *uses* of the expression, where as GHCi only has access to the constituent parts of the expression. GHC only defaults things that *remain* ambiguous after considering all of that extra context, so it isn't guaranteed to use the type for the expression that you would see with `:t +d` in GHCi.

For example:

```
n = 2^100 `div` 2

xs = "ABCD"

main = print $ xs !! n
```

This prints `'A'`, which is obviously not the 633825300114114700748351602688th element of that (4-element) list. Because the expression `` 2^100 `div` 2 `` is *used* as an argument to `!!` (non-locally, via the `n` binding), and `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a` the type is chosen as `Int`, not the type that would be chosen by default without this context (`Integer`). Evaluating that expression as `Int` has a different result (0, due to overflow).

This means that when you're scratching your head over a type error in GHC and are using `:t +d` in GHCi to try to get more information, you need to be aware that you still might not be seeing the same type that GHC is actually using. The polymorphic type is guaranteed to be compatible with the one GHC is using, but defaulting it in any other context might result in a different one that is not compatible.

Comment: That's a very useful addition to the answer!